# Width 100% bigger than parent div

Tags: html, css

If you go to this link:

http://benliger.webatu.com/

and click on portfolio, then click one of the squares you will see what i mean. The div is about 40px bigger than its parent even though it has a width of 100%? Have tried fiddling round with bordersizing: border box but can't get it to work...

```
HTML:

<div class="portfoliocontainer pagedown" style="display: block;">


<div class="portfoliopod podexpanded">
<img class="portfolioimage" src="aboutme.jpg">
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">testing 123</div>
</div>

CSS:

.portfolioimage {
width: 100%;
}

.portfoliopodmessage {

width:100%;
height:100px;
color:white;
background-color:black;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.portfoliopod {
float:left;
width:287px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px;
overflow:hidden;
height: 287px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.podexpanded {
width:100% !important;

}

.portfoliocontainer {
min-width: 941px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.9);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-1500px)!important;
-ms-transform: translateY(-1500px)!important;
transform: translateY(-1500px)!important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
max-width: 901px;
height: auto;
min-height: 800px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.31);
border-width: 1px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: not even an attempt shown here? Nor one bit of code? please amend your question to include this information.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Try giving the element `margin:0 -40px` so it will go outside of it's parent's bounding

Comment: Done, and apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add box-sizing to .podexpanded, then the css become:

```
.podexpanded {
     width: 100% !important;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding-right: 20px;
}
```

and remove margin-left from the .portfoliopod a and add padding-left, then the css become:

```
.portfoliopod {
     float: left;
     width: 287px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 287px;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the `margin-left:20px` for the styling on `.portfoliopod`.

Take out the `margin-left:20px` when a user clicks on an image when the style `.podexpanded` is applied and change the width of the image inside, while applying a `margin: 0 auto; display:block;` to the image within the expanded pod.

```css
.podexpanded {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.podexpanded img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure i really follow how the code it behaving. Are you saying that width 100% does not take into account any margins on the parent div? Having a width of 95% is not really an adequate solution as it will next span the width i want it to...

Comment: Right, 100% width does not take into account the `margin-left:20px`, making the width of the div actually 100% + 20px.